# Error after giving command "pip install langchain"

Tags: python, pip, package, langchain

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build aiohttp frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I tried to install langchain package in vscode using the command pip install langchain.

expected : the package should get installed.

actual :  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for yarl
Failed to build aiohttp frozenlist multidict yarl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, frozenlist, multidict, yarl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Which python are you using in VSCode? python from `python.org` or `mingw-compiled` Python ?

Comment: [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest) is happy to install [langchain](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/langchain) for you.

Comment: langchain fail video [langchain fail](https://youtu.be/ygehmBjwtiw).

Comment: @Goku-standswithPalestine I'm using the version from python.org, additional information, I'm getting the same error than OP, but I also see "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/" but I have the version 14.36.32532 installed

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below steps.

Create a virtual environment using the command

```
 python -m venv my_venv_name
```

Activate the virtual environment by executing source

```
  my_venv_name/bin/activate
```

PIP install libraries

```
  pip install langchain
  pip install """Other required libraries like OpenAI etc.
```

You should now successfully able to import

```
 from langchain.llm import OpenAI
```

Lastly when executing the code, make sure you are pointing to correct interpreter in your respective editor